# Where can I find the symbol of BNC in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, bnc, symbol

I am working with LTspice and I need to put a BNC at the input of my amplifier. Where can I find this symbol?

[image]

Comment: For what purpose do you want to have a connector model? For simulation  you would ignore the connector and connect the source directly to the circuit unless it's some special situation (very high frequency etc.) where the connector affects the signal.

Comment: it is not to simulate. it's just to have a clear card interface with all the components that I will need

Comment: That's not the purpose of LTSpice. LTSpice does simulation. It doesn't care about connectors, because connectors are just wires (eventually with additional parasitic resistance/capacitance/inductance/whatnot that you can model). LTSpice is not a tool for making an accurate schematic, and from which you can output a full Bill Of Materials. There are other tools for this, such as KiCad.

Comment: Ok thank you verry much, I created a symbol of a BNC so that I could put it on my shema

Answer (score 1):

You can use a net label for it.
Add a net named for example "BNC" or "BNC_Input". This will not provide a suitable image but will allow the function to be shown.

Comment: This could use further explanation

Answer (score 1):

LTspice is not a general-purpose schematic tool. There’s no point to such a symbol, since you must connect the input from a source. There are no connectors involved.

If you want to model a connector’s parasitics, you can design your own sub circuit for it, and can then also provide a custom symbol for it.

Do not use LTspice as a schematic tool. You’ll be fighting an uphill battle that’s not worth it.